# Chromedriver doesn't have enough permission, even tough i'm the only admin on this machine

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write a bot script with Python and Selenium. I downloaded the .zip file with Chromedriver inside, extracted the .exe and linked it in my script. When i tried to run it, i get the following error:

```
C:/Users/Jo/Desktop/Programming/Python/MessengerScript/Selenium-Writer.py:12: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jo/Desktop/Programming/Python/MessengerScript/Selenium-Writer.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\chromedriver.exe',chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Jo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 86, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

The .exe for chromedriver is in the "scripts" folder in my Python installation folder, so it is in the PATH variable of Windows. I've tried to set the .exe to "Run as admin" in the properties section and change the inheritance option of the folders, still didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')

name = input('Enter the name of user or group : ')
msg = input('Enter the message : ')
count = int(input('Enter the count : '))

#Scan the code before proceeding further
input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
user.click()

msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-container')

for i in range(count):
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('compose-btn-send').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mention the path where you have saved your `chromedriver.exe` and pass it to `webdriver`.

```
path = "<THE_PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER.EXE>"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly, i still get the same error, even if i define the path manually.

Comment: There is another possibility that I can think of. Maybe your `chromedriver.exe` is present in the "Programs" folder (where often there are restrictions). So try this as well. 1. Make a new folder in `C:` drive and name is it as 'chromedriver'. 2. Place your `chromedriver.exe` in this folder. 3. Add the PATH of this folder in the environment variables. 4. Try to run the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the `chromedriver.exe` in `C:\Windows` this folder. then use

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

If you keep the `chromedriver.exe` file in any others folder you can use the code.
You should mention the `PATH` with Options

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'DRIVER_PATH',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me the erroro which says that the executable may have the wrong permissions.

Comment: What ```OS``` you are using?

Comment: Windows 10, my account is an administrator, which makes all of this even more confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still won't work. I checked the error log again, it seems like Windows throws an Error 5, which is pretty weird, since i set the .exe tu run in admin mode.

Comment: Edited the error in the question, now it conatins everything that has been thrown out. The german bit behind [WinError5] means "Access denied".